# Exported metafiles have unwanted space--how to remove?

Tags: graphics

If I export an .emf or .wmf image file, once I import into MS Word, they have irregular space around the plots/tables that I have to manually crop off. How to I remove this space? If I export PNG or other bitmap file, there is no space around my image.

Comment: Did you try right-click onto graphics and choose "trim bounding box"?

Comment: that would be great, but not an option. I have to manually crop it. But the real reason I ask is because I'm using a matlab script to place my 100+ mathematica images in a word document and I'd want them to go in without any manual tweaking needed. What governs the bounding box size inn mma? can't it be changed? thanks!

Comment: Actually, I didn't see any problems with `Export` of .wmf in MMa 11.3 as well as trimming option in context menu. But it is in earlier versions.

Comment: Hmm. We are using MMA 11.0.1.0 here and both .wfm and .emf give off-centered boxes when brought into MS Word and in Word, I don't have the "trim bounding box" option to fix it.